# What is using trillions of inodes on my almost empty server?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, inode, corruption

I have `18446744069923968593` inodes (which seem really too much) and much more problematic: I have `18446744069414835186` used so the system won't create any other file (even if the disk is almost empty).

Result from my `df -i`

[image]

And I have a really problem which I didn't find a solution for: the inode sum is from far equals to the trillions you see on the picture.

For this command (`for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done`), I got this

```
/aquota.group
1
/aquota.user
1
/bin
125
/boot
1
/dev
64
/etc
1880
/fastboot
1
/home
1
/lib
483
/lib64
2
/media
1
/mnt
1
/opt
1
/proc
13972
/root
100746
/run
72
/sbin
114
/srv
1
/sys
350
/tmp
1180
/usr
145583
/var
6739
```

Which is obviously way less than the trillions you saw.

Comment: Does `fsck` report anything?

Comment: If it's openvz, you should talk to your hoster...

Comment: @roaima I really would like to but it says quota exceeded :'(

Comment: Does 250866 inodes used out of 509384273 sound plausible? It looks like some kind of 32-bit/64-bit whackiness. I second the advice to contact your hoster, the bug is likely in software that's under their control.

Comment: Your filesystem driver is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning!

Following the advices of @Guido, I saw that I need to reboot the system (`error 2`) and that's what I did.

The only problem that I got was that the server wasn't booting anymore which leads me to the @frostschutz's comment (call your hoster). And it works, they allowed me new temp inodes and the restart made my inode count back to 256 000 (or something approaching).

I cleaned up the server and everything is working normally but I think @psusi is also partially right (something was really wrong).

Thanks